# how to put time and date of when the form was submitted in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a table in PHPMyAdmin, it stores all the data that is submitted by form and I have just added `current_timestamp` and now it shows the date and time of today.

I was asking if is there a PHP script that will add the date and time for the previous forms that was submitted before I added `current_timestamp`

Comment: It sounds like when you insert a row, it stores a timestamp.  If submitting a form inserts a new row ... you'll have another timestamp. ISubmitting a new form updates an existing row ... then you'll overwrite the old timestamp with the new one.  If you want a "huistory" of your updates ... then you'll need to create a new "history" table: into which you'll insert a new row for each update.  Q: Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two columns in your table. First column 'created_at' and second column 'updated at'. 'created_at' will store timestamp when new record is created during form submission and 'updated_at' will shows timestamp when any information of row is changed. Have a look at following link:

[Creating two current timestamps columns in mysql table](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/mysql-1293-incorrect-table-definition-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current_timestamp)

Comment: @Zlatan - Glad! it helps. Please, consider accepting my answer.